# Selecting a JSON object of arrays from a PostgreSQL table

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, select, postgresql-json

I have prepared a simple [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2c9c5/1) demonstrating my problem -

In a two-player game I store user chats in a table:

```
CREATE TABLE chat(
    gid integer,            /* game id */
    uid integer,            /* user id */
    created timestamptz,
    msg text
);
```

Here I fill the table with a simple test data:

```
INSERT INTO chat(gid, uid, created, msg) VALUES
    (10, 1, NOW() + interval '1 min', 'msg 1'),
    (10, 2, NOW() + interval '2 min', 'msg 2'),
    (10, 1, NOW() + interval '3 min', 'msg 3'),
    (10, 2, NOW() + interval '4 min', 'msg 4'),
    (10, 1, NOW() + interval '5 min', 'msg 5'),
    (10, 2, NOW() + interval '6 min', 'msg 6'),
    (20, 3, NOW() + interval '7 min', 'msg 7'),
    (20, 4, NOW() + interval '8 min', 'msg 8'),
    (20, 4, NOW() + interval '9 min', 'msg 9');
```

And I can fetch the data by running the SELECT query:

```
SELECT ARRAY_TO_JSON(
  COALESCE(ARRAY_AGG(ROW_TO_JSON(x)), 
           array[]::json[])) FROM (
SELECT
    gid,
    uid,
    EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM created)::int AS created,
    msg
FROM chat) x;
```

which returns me a JSON-array:

```
[{"gid":10,"uid":1,"created":1514813043,"msg":"msg 1"},
 {"gid":10,"uid":2,"created":1514813103,"msg":"msg 2"},
 {"gid":10,"uid":1,"created":1514813163,"msg":"msg 3"},
 {"gid":10,"uid":2,"created":1514813223,"msg":"msg 4"},
 {"gid":10,"uid":1,"created":1514813283,"msg":"msg 5"},
 {"gid":10,"uid":2,"created":1514813343,"msg":"msg 6"},
 {"gid":20,"uid":3,"created":1514813403,"msg":"msg 7"},
 {"gid":20,"uid":4,"created":1514813463,"msg":"msg 8"},
 {"gid":20,"uid":4,"created":1514813523,"msg":"msg 9"}]
```

This is close to what I need, however I would like to use "gid" as JSON object properties and the rest data as values in that object:

```
{"10": [{"uid":1,"created":1514813043,"msg":"msg 1"},
        {"uid":2,"created":1514813103,"msg":"msg 2"},
        {"uid":1,"created":1514813163,"msg":"msg 3"},
        {"uid":2,"created":1514813223,"msg":"msg 4"},
        {"uid":1,"created":1514813283,"msg":"msg 5"},
        {"uid":2,"created":1514813343,"msg":"msg 6"}],

 "20": [{"uid":3,"created":1514813403,"msg":"msg 7"},
        {"uid":4,"created":1514813463,"msg":"msg 8"},
        {"uid":4,"created":1514813523,"msg":"msg 9"}]}
```

Is that please doable by using the [PostgreSQL JSON functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-json.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for `json_object_agg` for that last step. Here is how I'd do it:

```
SELECT  json_object_agg(
          gid::text, array_to_json(ar)
        )
FROM    (
  SELECT  gid,
          array_agg(
            json_build_object(
              'uid', uid,
              'created', EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM created)::int,
              'msg', msg)
          ) AS ar
  FROM    chat
  GROUP BY gid
) x
;
```

I left off the `coalesce` because I don't think an empty array is possible. But it should be easy to put it back if your real query is something more complicated that could require it.